# how to refresh GridView data

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I'm building an app that is using GrirdView full of buttons. I realize that after I change a button colour, the gridView adapter won't updates it immediately. I tried changing the code several times, but It changed nothing.
This is my "game" functions(here I call drawTheMove, and afterwards tries to add a break using thread):

```
 if (isValid(p)) {
                    addChoice(p);
                    drawTheMove(btn);
                    if (!onePlayer) {
                        gameScreen.changeImageTurn(numOfClick);
                        turn++;//if there is only one player, keep the turn at "his side"
                    }
                    if (compLevel != 0) { //vs computer
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

drawTheMove:

```
 public void drawTheMove(Button btn) {
    btn.setText(Integer.toString(getNumOfClick()));
    Player player = getLastPlayerPlay();
    btn.setBackgroundResource(player.getImageId());
    gameScreen.board.gridViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    gameScreen.board.boardGrid.invalidateViews();
}
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but this is my getView from the adapter:

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    //checks if the gridview is new- to inflate only once.
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, viewGroup, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    //else- using the old holder.
    else {
        //using the Tag to save the findViewById
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    holder.btnSqure = changeBtnSize(holder.btnSqure);
    if(position!=0||postion0flag==false) {
        final Button btn = holder.btnSqure;//final to call in inner class.
        Point p = intPositionToPoint(position);
        gm.gameScreen.board.addButtonToCell(btn, p.x, p.y);
        holder.btnSqure.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (gm.getUserClicks) {
                    Point p = intPositionToPoint(position);
                    gm.game(p, btn);
                    // gm.game(p, gm.cells[p.x][p.y].getButton());
                }
            }
        });
    }
    if(position==0)
        postion0flag=true;

    return row;
}
```